# Getting Ci to output am/pm in formatted mdate string

Tags: codeigniter

How would go about adding AM/PM to the ending of the following code snippet? So for it outputs  like this: 04/21/2012 07:59.

```
<?=mdate('%m/%d/%Y %H:%i', strtotime($row->entryCreationDateTime))?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're trying to use this in a query, you could use `date`. From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), AM/PM are given by "A":

```
<?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i A', strtotime($row->entryCreationDateTime)); ?>
```

As an aside, it's generally a [good idea to avoid short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) in your code.

Comment: This makes them all AM though when some are PM as well. How do I figure out if it's Am or Pm?

Comment: "A" stands in for AM or PM in the `date` function...maybe a problem with the timestamps you're using? Can you give an example (i.e., the value of `$row->entryCreationDateTime`, before it's parsed with `strtotime`)?

Comment: So that one *is* an AM..do you have one of the should-be-PMs that isn't rendering correctly?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry lol I didn't notice I just added that one. Here you go: 2012-04-21 07:57:58

Comment: Hmm, still an AM. Unless it's marked AM/PM in the timestamp or running on a 24-hour clock (e.g., `19:57:58`) it's going to be tough for `strtotime` to guess which one you mean.

Comment: I'm using NOW() in the sql insertion statement. What other function could I use that'll add the am/pm to the end?

Comment: NOW() should be fine -- it operates on the 24 hour clock.

Comment: So why I'm getting AM and not PM is unknown. I guess I'll just wait till the pm and test to see if it really works or not. I'm pretty sure I didn't post of my posts in the am though

Comment: Actually it is working. I've noticed all of my post dates are the same. I was debugging something and I had to go in and make all the post dates the same. I pulled some much older posts in and the PM is showing up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Quick question though, if I replace 'A' with 'P', what does that do?

Comment: From the documentation, "P: Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)". So, something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's

```
# 'AM' or 'PM' - upper case 'A'
<?=mdate('%m/%d/%Y %H:%i A', strtotime($row->entryCreationDateTime))?>
```

or

```
# 'am' or 'pm' - lowercase 'a'
<?=mdate('%m/%d/%Y %H:%i a', strtotime($row->entryCreationDateTime))?>
```